Возможно ли одновременное использование стека TCP/IP разными программами?
Есть 2 программы - браузер и простейший анализатор трафика(использует raw socket).
Не могу понять, как одни и те же данные, которые принимает браузер, принимаются одновременно вместе с анализатором трафика.
Возможно ли одновременное использование стека TCP/IP разными программами?
И если да, то как разные программы могут взаимодействовать со стеком TCP/IP, принимая одни и те же данные (как в примере выше)?
Спасибо.

@AlexF Знаю про драйвер, но в моем случае анализатор трафика простейший, как я уже упомянул - с использованием raw sockets.

Одновременное использование возможно, но в вашем случае его нет. Raw сокет ничего не знает о ip.

@eri, вы имеете в виду, что при использовании tcp-сокетов два и более процесса могут принимать данные, предназначенные одному порту? Можете пояснить?

@eri в моем случае raw socket принимает данные на низовом уровне (с сетевого интерфейса). Т.е. анализатор трафика забирает все данные предназначенные для браузера. При этом в браузер они также поступают. Как такое возможно?

Он их не забирает, а корирует
